# Bash - output identify output to new line

Tags: bash

I found this command online and it says it should print each output line to a new line in a file, but it doesnt.

```
find ./dir -name "*.jpg" -exec identify -format '%i 1 0 0 %w %h' \{\} \; > out.txt
```

Something along these lines:

```
find ./dir -iname "*.jpg" -exec echo \{\} 1 0 0 100 40 \; > out.txt
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

The output I get is:

```
./dir/1.jpg 1 0 0 916 1040./dir/10.jpg 1 0 0 496 588./dir.....
```

What I am after is:

```
./dir/1.jpg 1 0 0 916 1040    
./dir/10.jpg 1 0 0 496 588
```

Comment: Cam you provide an example of output you expect to get?

Comment: don't escape the `{}` - use `identify ..... {} \;`

Comment: @jm666 Shouldn't make any difference since `{}` is processed by `find`

Comment: @BroSlow yes, this wasn't mean as an answer, only a comment - it is to hairy using escaped `\{\}` instead of the simple `{}`. ;)

Comment: added output to post

Comment: Works for me.  Sounds like you are doing something like `var=$(find ...); echo $var`.  The fix is to use `echo "$var"` with double quotes.

Comment: the second line of code does works, but the first one with identify gives the output on same line. my aim is to have the output of the first basically look like the output of the second.

Comment: What version of identify are you using? That command works here with `6.7.7-10 2014-09-03 Q16`. Does adding `\n` to the end of the format string help you?

Comment: brilliant that fixed it. if you post that as an answer i can close the q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if you add a `\n` to the end of `'%i 1 0 0 %w %h'` to indicate a newline.